# How to built a SDN fat-tree topology using dockers? No Mininet

Tags: python, ubuntu, sdn, ryu

I'm setting up a fat tree topology with OVS - SDN in two servers using dockers. I built 7 switches (docker containers) and 4 hosts which will be connected to the access switches.

- 1 core switch
- 2 aggregation switches
- 4 access switches
- 4 hosts

Now I am trying to connect them each other to have the fat tree topology but no success.

---

#### PROBLEM 1: How to connect the containers in fat tree topology?

I created an overlay network between the servers and I have ping between containers from different servers but when I enable OVS, I have no ping by the  overlay. It is like the overlay is not allowing OVS flows.

---

#### PROBLEM 2: OVS is not working with overlay command

```
sudo docker swarm init docker swarm join --token SWMTKN-1-25m7jrn90nhn0gs6kzfzygvixbiudzszoceqhkygcqnwn5h48v-4i6t75vwax7yp9otd3v0f5kkn 192.168.1.60:2377
sudo docker run -itd --net=SDN_overlay --name=Osw_core1 --ip 10.28.0.30 --cap-add NET_ADMIN new_sw13
```

#### PROBLEM 3: How can I do my OVS- SDN fat tree topology with real servers?

I do not want to use MININET. Instead of dockers, what can I do to virtualize my switches?